# Is CoovaChilli suitable for large number of users?

Tags: coovachilli

I recently did a Freeradius + CoovaChilli solution to a small WISP. Recently, a larger ISP has approached me, they want me to deploy a similar setup.

My question is the number of clients CoovaChilli can handle simultaneously. The ISP talks of 70 000 users connected at a go.

Answer (score 1):

yes using vlan you can handle simultaneously

Here is Documentation:https://www.scribd.com/document/370649998/How-to-Configure-CoovaChilli-to-Support-VLAN